# tkinter: object with different movement patterns

Tags: python, class, object, tkinter

I'm working on a simulation in which some cubes of the same class are moving randomly. My aim is to give them another moving pattern, when they fulfill some characteristics (for example their object number).

#### My Problem:

If they fulfill the characteristics, how can I "switch off" the first moving pattern and activate the next?

Here a strongly simplified example of the simulation, and how it doesn't work:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *


class Cubes:
    def __init__(self, master, canvas, number, x1, y1, color):
        self.master = master
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.number = number
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.x2 = x1 + 15
        self.y2 = y1 + 15
        self.color = color
        self.rectangle = canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, self.x2, self.y2, fill=color)

    def movement(self):
        self.x = randint(-10, 10)
        self.y = randint(-10, 10)
        canvas.move(self.rectangle, self.x, self.y)
        if self.number == 2:
            def movementII(self):
                canvas.move(self.rectangle, 0, 0)
            self.canvas.after(100, self.movementII)
        self.canvas.after(100, self.movement)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    master = Tk()
    canvas = Canvas(master, width=900, height=600)
    canvas.pack()
    master.title("Simulation")
    cube = Cubes(master, canvas, 2, randint(50, 800), randint(25, 500), "black")
    cube.movement()

mainloop()
```

Comment: The universal [`after()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190222214221id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) widget method returns an integer “after identifier” that can be passed to the `after_cancel()` method if you want to cancel the callback. So that is how you can switch them "off". To have a changeable movement pattern, you will need to abstract that and make it an attribute of your `Cube` class.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I "switch off" the first moving pattern and activate the next?

When you call `after`, it returns a unique identifier. You can save that identifier and then later pass it to `after_cancel` to cancel the job if it hasn't already run.

I'm not entirely clear what you want, but if you want to turn off the old movement when you switch to the new, it would look something like this:

```
class Cubes:
    def __init__(self, master, canvas, number, x1, y1, color):
        ...
        self.after_id = None
        ...

    def cancel(self):
        if self.after_id is not None:
            self.after_cancel(self.after_id)
            self.after_id = None

    def movement(self):
        self.x = randint(-10, 10)
        self.y = randint(-10, 10)
        canvas.move(self.rectangle, self.x, self.y)

        if self.number == 2:
            def movementII(self):
                canvas.move(self.rectangle, 0, 0)
            self.cancel()
            self.after_id = self.canvas.after(100, self.movementII)

        self.after_id = self.canvas.after(100, self.movement)
```

A better way might be to have a single method that you call with `after`, and it simply calls the appropriate method.

For example, something like this:

```
def move(self):
    if self.number == 1:
        self.movement_1()
    elif self.number == 2:
        self.movement_2()

    self.canvas.after(100, self.move)

def movement_1(self):
    self.x = randint(-10, 10)
    self.y = randint(-10, 10)
    canvas.move(self.rectangle, self.x, self.y)

def movement_2(self):
    canvas.move(self.rectangle, 0, 0)
```

Then, to switch the movement method, just change `self.number` and it will automatically be called at the appropriate time.